# How to show that $\mathbb{C}[X/G] = \mathbb{C}[X]^{G}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a variety and $G$ a group acting on $X$. How to show that $\mathbb{C}[X/G] = \mathbb{C}[X]^{G}$? Here $\mathbb{C}[X]^{G} = \{f \in \mathbb{C}[X]: f(g.x) = f(x), g \in G\}$. Thank you very much.

Edit: assume that $X$ is an algebraic group. For example, $X = SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $G = N$ the unipotent subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ consisting of all upper triangular unipotent matrices.

Comment: For arbitrary groups $X/G$ may not be a scheme. Can you tell us what you mean?

Comment: @Mohan, thank you for your comments. I edited my post.

Comment: What is your definition of $X/G$ ? Usually it is defined as $Spec(\Bbb C[X]^G)$. Maybe you should look a book of geometric invariant theory, e.g Mukai, "Introduction to Invariant and Moduli".